# PHP's preg_match() returns only the match value

Tags: php, preg-match

I am doing the following:

```
$text = 'L\' utente _{nickname} ti ha invitato a giocare';

$text_vars = preg_match('#\_{(.*?)\}#', $text, $matches);
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => _{nickname}
    [1] => nickname
)
```

How can it be made to only return the following?

```
Array
(
    [0] => nickname
)
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Does the need to access `[1]` bother you so much? Aside from that, you'll probably want `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) documentation:

> If `matches` is provided, then it is filled with the results of
>   search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full
>   pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first
>   captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

---

For the desired behavior, use [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) like this:

```
$text = 'L\' utente _{nickname} ti ha invitato a giocare';
$text_vars = preg_match('#\_{(.*?)\}#', $text, $matches);
$temp = array_shift( $matches );
```

Comment: Yes ok, but I need to do more work on that matches, so I only need the matched value in the array, so the value I am looking for.

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
$text = 'L\' utente _{nickname} ti ha invitato a giocare';
$text_vars = preg_match('#\_{(.*?)\}#', $text, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';

echo $text_vars;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead `(?=..)` and a lookbehind `(?<=..)` (or a match reset `\K`)

```
$text_vars = preg_match('~(?<=_{)[^}]++(?=})~', $text, $match);
```

Or

```
$text_vars = preg_match('~_{\K[^}]++(?=})~', $text, $match);
```